# Trouble Installing Python with Framework-style Build (OS X)

Tags: python, pip, homebrew, easy-install

In attempting to get started learning and developing python, I've tried to follow the [Python Guide to installing python on OS X](https://python-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/), but haven't found it particularly "noob friendly."  I have a new MacBook (Mtn. Lion - OS X 10.8.3) wich comes with Python 2.7.2 built in. But the guide advises installing a "framework-style build" via homebrew. So:

1. I installed homebrew via `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"`
2. Then it tells you to add homebrew to the top of your `PATH` by adding it to your `~/.bashrc` file.  `ls -a` showed that I did not have a `~/.bashrc` file in my home directory. After searching Stack Overflow on how to do that, I ran `nano ~/.bashrc`, and inserted the line `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to the file and saved the file.
3. I then ran `brew install python --framework` and the install completed.
4. Then, the guide says to "add the new Python scripts directory to your `PATH`" so, I'm assuming that means I need to add the line it provides to my `~/.bashrc` file also. So, I added `export PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH` to my `~/.bashrc` file *above* my previous entry.
5. Finally, this is where I run into trouble, it says to `easy_install pip`. However, when I do that I get an [error 13](https://superuser.com/questions/391497/os-x-lion-easy-install-requires-sudo).

So, here are the things I need some help with.

1. **Was I correct in my assumptions about how to add homebrew and python scripts to my `PATH`?**
2. **Did I do something wrong or do I just need to use `sudo` to install pip?** (I'm really sorry if the answer is already on [this page](https://superuser.com/questions/391497/os-x-lion-easy-install-requires-sudo) but even those answers don't make total sense to me and I want to be careful and not screw something up)
3. **After installing the framework-style build of python (which I believe was the current 2.7.3), how come running `python` in my terminal still shows v2.7.2?**

Thanks! I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've tried to follow the Python Guide to installing python on OS X,
>   but haven't found it particularly "noob friendly.

Yes, I think it is misleading/outdated.

> Then it tells you to add homebrew to the top of your PATH by adding it
>   to your ~/.bashrc file. ls -a showed that I did not have a ~/.bashrc
>   file in my home directory. After searching Stack Overflow on how to do
>   that, I ran nano ~/.bashrc, and inserted the line export
>   PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH to the file and saved the file.

On the Mac, just use ~/.profile

> I then ran brew install python --framework and the install completed.

I think you don't need the --framework option unless you want to replace your Mac OS default installation and need an Mac OS Framework-style directory layout. There is no need to replace it though, the homebrew installation will take precedence anyway.

> Then, the guide says to "add the new Python scripts directory to your
>   PATH" so, I'm assuming that means I need to add the line it provides
>   to my ~/.bashrc file also. So, I added export
>   PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH to my ~/.bashrc file above my
>   previous entry.

Again, do it in ~/.profile. And don't forget to do a

```
source ~/.profile
```

otherwise the changes will only become active in any new terminal window, not the one you are currently using.

> Finally, this is where I run into trouble, it says to easy_install
>   pip. However, when I do that I get an error 13.

The error shows that you try to install it your Mac OS system's default Python library (rather than in /usr/local, homebrew style), which would require root privileges. Just don't.
Also, with homebrew python, pip is already installed.

Check your path:

```
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/pip
[..] /usr/local/bin/pip -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.3/bin/pip
```

Added bonus: Then do

```
pip install virtualenv
```

and use that.

And to your questions:

> Was I correct in my assumptions about how to add homebrew and python
>   scripts to my PATH?

Yes, but use .profile and do a `source .profile` afterwards.

> Did I do something wrong or do I just need to use sudo to install pip?
>   (I'm really sorry if the answer is already on this page but even those
>   answers don't make total sense to me and I want to be careful and not
>   screw something up)

You don't need sudo with homebrew, and pip is installed automatically with homebrew python.

> After installing the framework-style build of python (which I believe
>   was the current 2.7.3), how come running python in my terminal still
>   shows v2.7.2?

Probably PATH not correct, do `echo $PATH` and check that it is correct. That is unrelated to being "framework-style" or not, though.

Comment: thanks! I ran `python` again and it came up with version 2.7.3 after all. Perhaps I just had to restart terminal? I've done what you've suggested and it looks like I'm good to go.

Comment: However, now it appears I have another issue :(. I've made it a separate question if you care to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513840/distributionnotfound-error-after-upgrading-pip

Comment: error 13 is because the easy_install from OS X needs sudo. But don't do it because it will install into /Library/Python/2.7 and then conflict with the brewed python because all pythons are configured to look into /Library/Python/x.y/site-packages for modules. Homebrew installs pip and distribute, so you don't need them. The python guide has to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed python with homebrew, you should already have pip installed.  Try running

```
pip --version
```

to see whether and where `pip` is installed.  Hopefully it's in a `/usr/local/...` path where your other homebrew things live.

Also before you install too much more with `homebrew` be sure to run these commands:

```
brew update
brew doctor
```

Good luck!