# Stop Homebrew Pip putting virtualenv in /usr/local/share/

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, homebrew

I'm using python installed with Homebrew. It used to be the case that a brewed python's pip would put modules in `/usr/local/share/python`, but this [has been changed](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python#other---non-homebrew---python-bindings) in more recent versions of Homebrew, so that pip should put them in `/usr/local/bin`. But mine keeps putting them in `/usr/local/share/python`.

I've upgraded Homebrew, uninstalled python, reinstalled it, and am trying to install virtualenv with pip, but it keeps getting put in `/usr/local/share/python`. When trying to use it I get:

```
$ virtualenv
-bash: virtualenv: command not found
```

How do I make it stop putting things in there, like it's supposed to now?

I've got this working on one machine, but not on another, and both are using the same `$PATH` etc, so I'm stumped.

Comment: Where does it actually go?  You said `/usr/local/bin` in the first paragraph, and `/usr/local/share` in the second paragraph.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity - I've attempted to make it clearer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had the same problem, but I was able to fix it using the following solution (suggested by [DistributionNotFound error after upgrading pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513840/distributionnotfound-error-after-upgrading-pip)) and an additional command:

1. go to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages and remove:

   - easy-install.pth
   - pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg or other versions of pip you have.
   - distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg or other versions
2. `brew rm python`
3. `brew uninstall python` (for some reason `brew rm python` only removed python 2.7.3 in my Homebrew folder. `brew uninstall python` allows me to remove the newest python installation in the folder)
4. `brew install python`
5. `pip install --upgrade virtualenv`

Virtualenv should be installed to /usr/local/bin if you've followed the steps.

*If you have Macvim installed, it might crashes the setup. Just reinstall with brew install macvim --override-system-vim and everything will work ok.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks alwc! I don't actually understand why this fixes things... but it works.

Comment: @PhilGyford My theory is that previously there were two Python 2.7.x installed in Homebrew. When we were calling 'pip install virtualenv', we were using the old Python from Homebrew, which directs the path to /usr/local/share/python'. I'm glad that it works for you!